# Cmake: make static library and use in other projects

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I need to make library `test` and use it in other projects by `#include <libraryname>`

In project `test`:

CmakeLists.txt

```
...
add_library(libtest STATIC lib.h lib.cpp)
set_target_properties(libtest PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER lib.h)

install(TARGETS libtest
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
...
```

In project `testUseLibrary`:

CmakeLists.txt

```
...
add_executable(project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project PUBLIC libtest)
...
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <libtest> // error 

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

In project `testUseLibrary` `#include<libtest>` doesn't see library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `target_include_directories` to specify the include directories for your target. In this case, the directory where libtest resides.

Comment: Maybe there is a method exist to use find_library?

Comment: Your `libtest` project should create a [package configuration](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) and the consumer should do `find_package(libtest REQUIRED)`. The imported `libtest` target will then be usable there.